# mysqli connection php Media Temple

Tags: php, mysqli, mediatemple

I am coming from a mysql_select_db background and need to get up on mysqli.

I am having trouble connecting with mysqli to my database at Media Temple. **I have confirmed that the connection info is correct by connecting via php myAdmin on the MT server.** (000000 is substituted below).

my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("internal-db.000000.gridserver.com", "db000000", "password", "db000000_dbName");
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from 'users'"); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['fieldName']);
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'internal-db.000000.gridserver.com' (61) 

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli //this is because of the bad connection

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object //this is because of the bad connection
```

Here's a link on MT's site:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/4/Why+can%27t+I+connect+to+my+MySQL+database+from+PHP%3F#gs

What am I missing here? Thanks for reading.

Comment: so if you do the connect using mysql instead of mysqli - it works?!

Comment: And: how have you confirmed that the settings are all right - did you connect to the mysql server using the mysqlclient in the shell?

Comment: can you connect to the server via ssh and run " mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb" adapted to your settings - just to make sure that it works, e.g. that they do not skipped e.g. the port in the manual?

Comment: testing via ssh is up next.

Answer (score 1):

the server adress haves this format?

`internal-db.000000.gridserver.com`?

if you do a ping on `internal-db.000000.gridserver.com` do you get a IP?

Comment: Ping comes back with nothing, that address seems to be what they want, per edit I just posted.

Comment: does you passwords contains special characters  like `" or '`?

Only the 1st error is interresting, because other errors are due to the first

Comment: it seems to be ok, exclamation point doesn't affects php's string declarations

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is not being established for the host.  If this script is running on the same host as the database, just use *localhost* rather than the fully qualified host name. The error message will be different for a user name or remote access permission problem. This looks more like a networking (firewall) type issue.

Comment: the hoster shows some exemples and they use the subdomain, so i imagine they opened the firewall..

Comment: Potential issue if your not internal/local from MT site: For external connections, use external-db.s00000.gridserver.com instead and make sure your IP address has been added to the list of allowed external IPs. Click here for details.

Comment: mmh yeah interresting... @JWC_WDC did you simply tryed `localhost` ?

Comment: Yep I did try localhost, I'll try the external/IP next as well.

Comment: finally found (61) means: ECONNREFUSED ("Connection refused").